# How do I use paste and as.formula to generate a complex formula?

Tags: r, model, paste

I am attempting to input an equation using R in a loop, and so I am using `as.formula` and `paste.`
The end result should be:

```
library(nlme)
glm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length +Petal.Width, 
  family = gaussian(),data=iris)
```

Whether or not this is the right model, don't worry, its just an example. I have these variables broken up into 3 components

- Sepal.Length and Sepal.Width are 1 component
- Petal.Length + Petal.Width are 1 component
- family = gaussian(),data=iris) is another component

Why is this not working?

```
library(nlme)

glmi = glm(as.formula(paste("Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width+ ", 
           paste('Petal.Length +Petal.Width',
           paste(',', 'family = gaussian(),data=iris')))))
```

Comment: do `glm(reformulate(c("Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"),"Sepal.Length"),family=gaussian(),data = iris)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `formula` argument of `glm()` is only this bit:

```
Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length +Petal.Width
```

of your original code - `family = gaussian(), data=iris` are different `glm()` arguments, and don't belong in there.

Based on what you have, something like

```
glm(
  as.formula(paste("Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width+ ", paste('Petal.Length +Petal.Width'))),
  family = gaussian(),
  data=iris
)
```

would seem to be the equivalent of what you're trying.

I've left the unnecessary second `paste()` in there as presumably it corresponds to more complex logic that you've simplified for the question.